# How to set a hover event handler on a QPushButton in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to set a hover event on a button to open an options menu implemented as a QDialog. Everything works so far except the hovering: the menu opens when the button is pressed and disappears if any of the options is selected or the mouse is moved away from the dialog.

Now I want to open the window without clicking the button but rather by hovering over it.
I've seen [PyQt5 mouse hover functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291734/pyqt5-mouse-hover-functions) and [How to detect mouse hover event in PySide6 widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082399/how-to-detect-mouse-hover-event-in-pyside6-widget) but i wasn't able to make it work this way.

My code looks like this:

```
class ElementWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, p, element):
        super().__init__(p)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel(element)        
        label.setFixedSize(200,39)

        self.btn = QPushButton("btn")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self._openOptionsMenu)
        self.btn.setFixedSize(50,39)
        
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setFixedSize(250,60)  

    def _openOptionsMenu(self):
        self.dlg = selfClosingDialog(self.closeOptionsMenu, parent = self)
        
        self.dlg.setLayout(ElementOptionsLayout(self.closeOptionsMenu))
        self.dlg.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        
        self.dlg.setGeometry(QCursor.pos().x(), QCursor.pos().y() ,100,100)
        self.dlg.show()
        

    def closeOptionsMenu(self):
        self.dlg.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.resize(500,400)
    wid = ElementWidget(window,"Parabola_0")
    
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

with the custom dialog:

```
class selfClosingDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, closeFunc, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.closeFunc = closeFunc

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.closeFunc()
```

The perfect solution would be to replace the clicked-event by some kind of an onHover

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

It is not a signal but an event `enterEvent` that needs to be reimplemented by a subclass of QWidget

```
class HoverOpenBtn(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, openOtionsFunc, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.openFunc = openOtionsFunc

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.openFunc()
```

Comment: Note that you should also call the default implementation, which is important for styles that change the look of the widget when hovered (which is normally the case of buttons). Also, the implementation of the question you linked is wrong, since events should not be checked against their string representation, but with their enum (`event.type()`) against the [event type list](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum).